# Is it possible to get the value of a GUID on an interface using RTTI?

Tags: delphi, rtti

If I have an interface such as:

```
IPluginAPI = interface
['{590DFF0B-CA00-46CC-84B0-3848103D4C5A}']
   function add (a : double; b : double) : double;
   function sub (a : double; b : double) : double;
   function mult (a : double; b : double) : double;
   function divide (a : double; b : double) : double;
end;
```

Is there anyway to get the value of the GUID using RTTI? I am using Delphi XE.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
uses
  TypInfo;

Guid := GetTypeData(TypeInfo(IPluginAPI))^.Guid;
```

Comment: +1 Too bad the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/TypInfo.TTypeData) is so far out of date.......

Comment: Wow, that page is outright misleading. Note to self: Always see the source.

Comment: +1, another option using the new Rtti `TRttiInterfaceType(TRttiContext.Create.GetType(TypeInfo(IPluginAPI))).GUID`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by RRUZ in comment to older reply:

```
uses
  System.Rtti;

//...
var Guid := TRttiInterfaceType(TRttiContext.Create.GetType(TypeInfo(IPluginAPI))).GUID;
```

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Rtti.TRttiContext